# Using C#, how can I update a label when I select an item from a ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, label

Hy,

In my ASP.NET application I have a listbox with multiple items and a label.

How can I update the label text when I select one item from the listbox? For example, if I select 'First' item, then my label text will be 'First'?

Thank you
Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use javascript unless you have a reason to postback to the server.

Personally I like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It would look something like this:

```
$('#ListID').change(function() {
    $('#LabelID').text(this.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" to your listbox on the aspx page and in the code behind add something like this:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     lblYourLabel.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 }
```

This should set the text of your label to the text of the selected item in the listbox.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable AutoPostBack on that listbox (in design view arrow in upper right corner on control) and in Page_Load write:

Label.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;

But this will cause that every change on listBox reloads a page. You should user JavaScript for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ListBox to set the text of the label to the selected items value.

Something like:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="listBox_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
<asp:Label ID="YourLabel" runat="server" />
```

and in the codebehind:

```
protected void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, eventargs e) {
     YourLabel.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```